# Launch condition in WIX to check advertise mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am running my MSI from command prompt with /jm option. I want to add a LaunchCondition in my WIX file to check whether the MSI is triggered with /jm option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered the ADVERTISE property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367547(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I got the answer after doing a little bit of research: To stop advertise mode you can add Allowadvertise = "no", in the feature block in wix. This will stop advertise mode, if MSI is triggered from comma line with ADVERTISE=ALL property set. Still looking for a way to restrict advertise mode from SCCM install.

Comment: Thanks JohnL, I got ADVERTISE from the MSDN link. But here is my requirement. I am still not able to disable advertise mode fully for my MSI.

Comment: Why is it necessary to disable advertisement mode?

Answer (score 1):

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/advertiseexecutesequence.html

Try using the `AdvertiseExecuteSequence` tag. You can create an error action to prevent any advertised installations from taking place. Just place the error at the beginning of the sequence.

Initialize the error action:

```xml
<CustomAction Id="ErrorMessageId" Error="Insert error message here"/>`
```

Run the error action:

```
<AdvertiseExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="ErrorMessageId" Before="CostInitialize"/>
</AdvertiseExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every feature can go into advertised state. One easy way would be to edit the .msi, if possible and add the "msidbFeatureAttributesDisallowAdvertise" (8) and maybe the "msidbFeatureAttributesUIDisallowAbsent" (16) attribute to the MSI feature table. (I don't work with WiX so you will find out yourself).

Another way would be to add a custom action who controls if the ADVERTISE property is nonempty and just abort the installation.

Changing the feature action from advertise to install local would be quite tricky but maybe possible.

If you have a path (.msp) there are other ways to protect it from being installed with features in advertised mode.